# Is it possible to alias a class template in C++?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
  template <typename T1>
  struct B {};
};

template <typename T>
using b = A<T>::B;
```

The line above refuses to compile.

clang gives this error:
use of class template 'A< T>::type' requires template arguments

Comment: missing typename, A<T>::B is a dependant type.

Comment: `struct A` could have a template specialization where `A<int>::B` (for example) could be a static variable instead of a type. So for the compiler, you have to specify that you're expecting `A<T>::B` to be a type by writing `typename` before it.

Answer (score 3):

because B is template should it provided a template argument

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
  template <typename T1>
  struct B {};
};

template <typename T,typename  T1>
using b =   typename  A<T>::template B<T1>;
```